# Use hook to get the domain configuration from language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, configuration

We have enabled English, Spanish, and French on our site. On *Regional and language >> Languages detection* we selected *URL* for *Content language detection >> Detection Method*. For *Part of the URL that determines language*, we selected *Domain*. We then set the following domains.

- English: example.com
- Spanish: es.example.com
- French: fr.example.com

How can we programmatically obtain the domain associated to each language? What code should we use in a preprocess function?
Using the following code, we obtained the list of the language, but we are far
 from getting the domain that has been associated with each language.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // to get all enabled languages
  $languages = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguages();

  // Did not find method to retrieve the domain configuration.
  foreach($languages as $key => $value) {
    ksm($languages[$key]);
    //stuck here on how to get domain configuration per language.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain associated with each language is stored as configuration. Using the following code, `$prefix` will contain the prefix, and `$domain` the domain used.

```
  $config = \Drupal::configFactory()->get('language.negotiation');
  $languages = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguages();
  $prefixes = $config->get('url.prefixes');
  $domains = $config->get('url.domains');
  foreach ($languages as $langcode => $language) {
    $prefix = $prefixes[$langcode];
    $domain = $domains[$langcode];
  }
```

I wrote the code basing on [`NegotiationUrlForm::buildForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21language%21src%21Form%21NegotiationUrlForm.php/function/NegotiationUrlForm%3A%3AbuildForm/8.8.x), which is the form builder for the form that sets the negotiation URL for each language.

Comment: that got me exactly what i needed using the `$config = \Drupal::configFactory()->get('language.negotiation');`